# Python lock class attribute while main thread is executing

Tags: python, python-multithreading

My main script launches an API and another thread executes a daily task to update data.
Currently, the daily update can change data during an API call and it will cause an error.

I think my problem can be summarized as the following code :

```
import schedule
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time


def periodically_run_pending_tasks(interval=0.5):
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(interval)


def change_state(item):
    item.a = "New state"


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "Initial state"

    def print_state_twice(self, lk):
        lk.acquire()
        print(self.a)
        time.sleep(2)
        print(self.a)
        lk.release()


my_class = MyClass()
lock = Lock()

thread = Thread(target=periodically_run_pending_tasks)
schedule.every().second.do(change_state, my_class)
thread.start()

my_class.print_state_twice(lock)
```

I want this script to output either twice *Initial state* or twice *New state* but it returns *Initial State* *New state*.

I've also tried :

```
import schedule
from threading import Thread, Lock
import time


def periodically_run_pending_tasks(interval=0.5):
    while True:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(interval)


def change_state(item):
    item.a = "New state"


class MyClass:
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = "Initial state"

    def print_state_twice(self, lk):
        lk.acquire()
        print(self.a)
        time.sleep(2)
        print(self.a)
        lk.release()


my_class = MyClass()
lock = Lock()

thread_2 = Thread(target=my_class.print_state_twice, args=(lock,))
thread_2.start()

thread = Thread(target=periodically_run_pending_tasks)
schedule.every().second.do(change_state, my_class)
thread.start()
```

Comment: *All* code that accesses a shared resource needs to use the lock. The lock doesn't automatically control access to resources used or modified while the lock is held. The lock only controls access to the lock itself.

Comment: Thank you, I've tried using the lock inside *change_state()* and it works